# Android method for ACTION_USER_PRESENT

Tags: android

I need to detect if the user is present. I already use a BroadcastReceiver with `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT` but in another class I need a method for this to check on the fly (for SDK>=21). Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

For example, for `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` I'm using this:

```
private boolean isScreenOn() {
    DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    for (Display display : displayManager.getDisplays()) {
        if (display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but I cannot find a corresponding way for USER_PRESENT. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`.

If you store that state as a static boolean, you can then listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` to reset it.

You can then check the state of your boolean to determine if the user is present. Though bear in mind this may not be ideal if the user has a long screen off timeout.

Comment: Yes that was one possibility but I thought there was one method for this. I check this as correct answer. Thank you